# Generate point cloud from struct type data in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, point-clouds

I have a struct file in matlab. I want to visualize x,y,z in a table in the struct as a point of cloud. How is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried and what is your existing code?

Comment: well i have read it with python and generated a csv file with x,y,z and intensity. But all the existing examples i see on github use the pcd, bin or ply formats. So I am confused how to use the csv in python itself or if it is possible to use the struct file in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

[Matlab's documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/3-d-point-cloud-processing.html) provides all of the information you need to get started on this problem!

Here is just link to get you started on [visualizing point clouds](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/display-point-clouds.html) with Matlab.

Please note that Matlab tends to want you to use the [computer vision toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/index.html) for point cloud processing.

Here is a quick example ([original link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/view-rotating-3-d-point-cloud.html)), of loading a point cloud file of a teapot.

**View Rotating 3-D Point Cloud**

Load point cloud.

```
ptCloud = pcread('teapot.ply');
```

Define a rotation matrix and 3-D transform.

```
x = pi/180; 
R = [ cos(x) sin(x) 0 0
     -sin(x) cos(x) 0 0
      0         0   1 0
      0         0   0 1];

tform = affine3d(R);
```

Compute x-*y* limits that ensure that the rotated teapot is not clipped.

```
lower = min([ptCloud.XLimits ptCloud.YLimits]);
upper = max([ptCloud.XLimits ptCloud.YLimits]);

xlimits = [lower upper];
ylimits = [lower upper];
zlimits = ptCloud.ZLimits;
```

Create the player and customize player axis labels.

```
player = pcplayer(xlimits,ylimits,zlimits);

xlabel(player.Axes,'X (m)');
ylabel(player.Axes,'Y (m)');
zlabel(player.Axes,'Z (m)');
```

Rotate the teapot around the z-axis.

```
for i = 1:360      
    ptCloud = pctransform(ptCloud,tform);     
    view(player,ptCloud);     
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `gridPoints.X`, `gridPoints.Y`, `gridPoints.Z` in the format (x, y) as `points3D(x, y, [1 2 3])`, just do this:

```
cacheAxes = char(fieldnames(gridPoints));
points3D = double.empty();
for i = 1:3
    points3D(:, :, i) = gridPoints.(cacheAxes(i));
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [pcshow()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html) command.
Use the x,y,z values you want as input, like

```
pcshow(x,y,z)
```